# How to add a vector element to every element of the subarray along the associated index of a multidimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm wondering if there is a more "numpythonic" or efficient way of doing the following:

Suppose I have a 1D array `A` of known length `L`, and I have a multidimensional array `B`, which has a dimension also with length `L`.  Suppose I want to add (or set) the value of `B[:, ..., x, ..., :] += A[x]`.  In other words, add the value `A[x]` to every value of the entire sub-array of `B` in the matching index `x`.

An extremely simple working example is this:

```
A = np.arange(10, 20)
B = np.random.rand(3, len(A), 3)

for iii in range(len(A)):
    B[:, iii, :] += A[iii]
```

Clearly I can always loop over the index I want as above, but I'm curious if there's a more efficient way.  If there's some more common terminology which describes this process, I'd also be interested because I'm having difficulty even constructing an appropriate Google search.

I'm also attempting to avoid creating a new array of the same shape as `B` and tiling the `A`-vector repeatedly over other indices and then adding that to `B`, as a more "real" world application would likely involve `B` being a relatively large array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your simple case, you can do:

```
B[:] = A[:, None]
```

This works because of [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html). By simulating the dimensions of `B` in `A`, you tell numpy where to place the elements unambiguously. For a more general case, where you want to place `A` along dimension `k` of `B`, you can do:

```
B[:] = np.expand_dims(A, tuple(range(A.ndim, A.ndim + B.ndim - k)))
```

[`np.expand_dims`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) will add axes at the indices you tell it to. There are other ways too. For example, you can index `A` with `B.ndim - k - 1` instances of `None`:

```
B[:] = A[(slice(None), *(None,) * (B.ndim - k - 1))]
```

You can also use [`np.reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) to get the correctly shaped view:

```
B[:] = A.reshape(-1, *np.ones(B.ndim - k - 1, dtype=int))
```

OR

```
B[:] = A.reshape(-1, *(1,) * (B.ndim - k - 1))
```

OR

```
B[:] = A.reshape((-1,) + (1,) * (B.ndim - k - 1))
```

In all these cases, you only need to expand the trailing dimensions of `A`, since that's how broadcasting works. Since broadcasting is such an integral part of numpy, you can simply relpace `=` with `+=` to get the expected result.